# How to convert mixed dates in MYSQL to yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: mysql, date, str-to-date

I have a text type column named **start_date** that contains many dates in 2 date different formats. One is **dd/mm/yyyy** and the other is **yyyy-mm-dd**.

I need to convert all dd/mm/yyyy dates to yyyy-mm-dd and then set the column data type to **date**.

```
UPDATE table_name SET start_date= str_to_date(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

So far I'm receiving "Error Code 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2014-03-01' for function str_to_date"

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One is `dd/mm/yyyy` and the other is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

If this is complete formats list then, for example, use

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET start_date= STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
WHERE LOCATE('/', start_date);
```